# How to filter a Graphql query with a field value in Laravel 5.8 with Lighthouse

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have users who can create lists. Lists can be starred ("featured" if you prefer). I want to build a Graphql query in Lighthouse/Laravel that would retrieve all the starred/featured lists for a given user.

I tried this query and it works:

```
clistsByStarred(user_id: Int! @eq, starred: Boolean! @eq): [Clist] @all
```

and then I can use it like that:

```
query {
  clistsByStarred(user_id: 1, starred: true) {
      id
      name
      starred
    }
}
```

But it feels like a dirty hack to me.

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
query {
   user(id: 1) {
     id
     name
     clistsByStarred {
       id
       name
       starred
     }
   }
 }
```

Any idea on how to implement it ?

Comment: In your user type add a field/relationship to clists and then you should be able to do it just like you did in your query with a argument and the eq directive. https://lighthouse-php.com/master/eloquent/relationships.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type User {
 id: ID!
 clists(starred: Boolean @eq): Clist @hasMany
```

This example gives you a user type which has a list of Clist types.
You then just add a field in your query to get a single user by id.

When you query this, you can then specify the parameter starred to only get the starred.

For this to work the relationship has to exist on your eloquent model.
https://lighthouse-php.com/master/eloquent/relationships.html

Comment: It used to work fine. But then I installed Passport and the [lighthouse-graphql-passport-auth plugin](https://github.com/joselfonseca/lighthouse-graphql-passport-auth) and it doesn't work anymore. Here is the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/SZTue26) of Graphql Playground. But the authentication works fine. Any idea why ?

Comment: Actually, the reason was that the plugin uses its own User type. Mine was overridden. Problem solved.